# Changing audio drivers in Ubuntu 18.0.4 so Line Out doesn't flicker and fuzz!

Tags: drivers, nvidia, sound, graphics, pulseaudio

I can see my machine recognizes card 0, card 1, etc. Card one Being the one that is not working. The other available drivers are Nvidia drivers. Will they handle sound too if I can get them to come up first on the list and how do I change the drivers? I have tried the different Nvidia driver packages and none of them fix the audio issue. 
I am running MSI 760GM P34(FX) mobo which the onboard audio is the one not working. All other audio is working like the headphones and the HDMI out of the graphics card. Do I need to just bite the bullet and get a new mobo or can I update the driver somehow? I haven't seen how to do so anywhere where I can understand it as I am a newb in linux. Just changing the audio drivers doesn't seem like it should be this hard.

Here is the output of aplay -l:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: SB [HDA ATI SB], device 0: ALC887-VD Analog [ALC887-VD Analog]
Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: Headset [Logitech USB Headset], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Comment: When something doesn't work, there is rarely any need change, update, rollback, ...or whatever you do, a device driver, let alone multiple drivers. Why don't you explain what the problem is in more details, and then we can try and help you. Also, add the output of `aplay -l` to the question.

Comment: I am getting no sound out from my Line Out audio at all. Though it shows as an option the choice in settings>sound is there but it flickers on and off while you watch it quickly on and off on and off... so I can use everything from the Nvidia sound card like HDMI out and I am also getting audio from the headphones. Output of aplay -l on next one.

Comment: Can you add the output to the question. It is unreadable as a comment.

Comment: So I have the drivers available it just doesn't use the nvidia drivers or even when I switch between inputs and they all work but the realtek onboard audio it seems to me the driver I have is corrupt or not the right driver even as the speakers pop and try to play sound but only like ham radio type noise. But I am coming from windows so what do I know about how linux works? nothing

Comment: There are no Nvidia audio drivers.

Comment: Oh ok so I wasn't sure I thought I read that you can use the Nvidia drivers for audio too is that not the case? I guess maybe my language is wrong but I see the Nvidia drivers under alsamixer and such but when I choose them nothing seems to change.

Comment: You don't see Nvidia drivers under alsamixer. You see a Nvidia device.

Answer (score 0):

I've found two similar problems marked as solved, that suggested adding  one of the following to `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`:

```
options snd-hda-intel model=6stack-dig
options snd-hda-intel model=generic
```

To do it, open a terminal window, run `sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`, add one of the lines to the end, hit Ctrl+o to save, Ctrl+x to close.

Info sources: [1](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1720017&page=2) and [2](https://debianforum.ru/index.php?topic=5630.0)

Comment: I added the line options snd-hda-intel model-generic to that file and the speakers popped when the audio attempted to play but it just sounded like a short wave radio like it always does just fuzz and static. I did get a cheap soundblaster card and it works so I have audio out now so if you're good I'm good but I just like to solve problems and learn so I'm game to keep trying anything just to know how Linux works and not let the PC have dominion over me! Thanks for the comments!